# Grouping data based on a specific pattern

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, unsupervised-learning

I have a collection of data for a multiplayer game (2000 games, 10 players each). I would like to create clusters from this data, each containing the ids of 3 players that had played against each other. For example, assume player A played against player B, B played against C, and C played against A. I'm trying to figure out a way to detect A,B, and C from the data. I was thinking of using kmeans but this may not work as i do not know the number of clusters. Please help

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How do i create groups/clusters representing 3 players that had all played against each other from the data

Comment: The data includes columns for match id, player id, team id, and Boolean for result

Comment: There is a lot of confusion in the question but it does not seem to be so unclear as to be unanswerable - even if the answer is not at all to do with clustering - so I don't think the question should be closed as unclear

Comment: What are you hoping for if A played against B, A against B, A against C, A against D, B against C, B against D, c against D? Or some variants of that?

Comment: Detecting a non transitive relation

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a statistics question.  Certainly not a clustering one.  I think it should be moved to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Silverfish How can you answer a question when no question is asked?

Comment: @Firebug It struck me that Anony-Mousse had penetrated the underlying confusion here - the OP seems mixed up between cliques and clusters. As it's a statistical misunderstanding I think it's at least arguable that it has a place here though I wouldn't argue against the consensus decision. (I felt the question was rather implicit.)

Comment: I apologize for the confusion in my question. I was not aware of cliques, the question i posted is part of a project i am working on for a data science course. I replied to Anony-Mousse's answer an update to what i have reached so far.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be looking for 3-Cliques, not for clusters.

Unless you are also looking for larger cliques, you likely won't find an "algorithm" for this, because it is straightforward.

```
For any node A:
  For any neighbors B < C of A:
    If A < B and B and C are connected:
      report ABC as 3-clique
```

Clustering algorithms try to solve a different problem, so they won't be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I researched cliques and understood that they are detected from graphs. I can use networkx to solve this in python. I read the documentation on networkx, but have not successfully managed to go about it. Do you know where i can find a good tutorial for solving this? I'm currently stuck in building a graph representation from the dataframe. My data columns are gameId, players ids under each team, and the outcome of the game for each team.